# How to call an other activity from parent activity by intent setclass?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to make an dynamical move activity process by using baseActivity through process of defined string value. 
But I've faced an problem of "activity is not an enclosing class." error in calling "newIntent.setClassName" method of baseActivity. 
Could you help some idea?

First, for explaining about the trying code,

This process purpose is for user sign up process.

Here is used activities. 
1. AgreeChildActivity (agree a service terms) 
2. VerifyingChildActivity (verifying an user) 
3. InputChildActivity (input an user info) 
4. CompleteChildActivity (show a service join completed)

1~4 These are children of "GateBaseActivity".

It starts the dynamical move process by onClick method of an "MainActivity".

```
MainActivity {
    String sProcessCase1 = "verifying->input->complete";
    String sProcessCase2 = "input->verifying->complete";
    String sProcessCase3 = "input->complete";

    :
    :

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = null;
        try {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.goDynamicMenu:
                   // start dynamic process
                   Intent newIntent = new Intent()
                   newIntent.setClassName(this, "AgreeChildActivity");
                   newIntent.putExtra("MOVE_SEQ", sProcessCase1);   <== set processCase.
                   startActivity(newIntent);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


// Following is each activities code.

GateBaseActivity (<= This is a parent of all process activity.) 
   void onResume() { (so executes this method when each process activity shows.)
       String sActivitySeq = getintent("MOVE_SEQ"); <= "verifying->input->complete"
       String sNextActivity = <= calculate the nextActivity name on sActivitySeq.  For simple, omitted. 
       // "verifying->input->complete"
       // verifying => VerifyingChildActivity
       // input => InputChildActivity
       // complete => CompleteChildActivity

       String sThisChildSimpleName = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

       Intent newIntent = new Intent();

       // execute here when childActivity is the "AgreeChildActivity".
       if ("AgreeChildActivity".equals(sThisChildSimpleName)) {
           newIntent.setClassName(AgreeChildActivity(<=Here occured "not an enclosing class err.", How to solve this error?).this, sNextActivity);
       }

       // execute here when childActivity is the "VerifyingChildAcitivty".
       else if ("VerifyingChildActivity".equals(sThisChildSimpleName)) {
           newIntent.setClassName(VerifyingChildActivity(<=Here occured "not an enclosing class err.", How to solve this error?).this, sNextActivity);
       }

       // execute here when childActivity is the "InputChildAcitivty".
       else if ("InputChildActivity".equals(sThisChildSimpleName)) {
           newIntent.setClassName(InputChildActivity(<=Here occured "not an enclosing class err.", How to solve this error?).this, sNextActivity);
       }

       // execute here when childActivity is the "CompleteChildActivity".
       else if ("CompleteChildActivity".equals(sThisChildSimpleName)) {
           newIntent.setClassName(CompleteChildActivity(<=Here occured "not an enclosing class err.", How to solve this error?).this, sNextActivity);
       }

       newIntent.putExtra("MOVE_SEQ", sActivitySeq);
       startActivity(intent); 
   }


// These are child activities of "GateBaseActivity".

AgreeChildActivity implement GateBaseActivity
   void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
       Log.d("autoTest", "Here is AgreeChildActivity.");
   }

VerifyingChildActivity implement GateBaseActivity
   void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
       Log.d("autoTest", "Here is VerifyingChildActivity.");
   }

InputChildActivity implement GateBaseActivity
   void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
       Log.d("autoTest", "Here is InputChildActivity.");
   }

CompleteChildActivity implement GateBaseActivity
   void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
       Log.d("autoTest", "Here is CompleteChildActivity.");
   }
```

Comment: Just use `this` instead of `AgreeChildActivity.this`.

Comment: I think just "this" is  "GateBaseActivity" but not current child activity of "GateBaseActivity".

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thanks.  "this" is correct.  MyCode had some mistake. :D

Answer (score 1):

Try-

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AgreeChildActivity.class);
```

You have to use existing activity context to start new activity, new activity is not created yet, and you cannot use its context or call methods upon it.

**not an enclosing class error** is thrown because of your usage of this keyword. this is a reference to the current object — the object whose method or constructor is being called. With this you can only refer to any member of the current object from within an instance method or a constructor.

Comment: Or simply use `this` as the context when within an Activity subclass.